# Getting list of available dates from rental app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am creating a ROR app for an e-commerce site which handles the management of renting items for a period of time. The items will be physically delivered and picked-up. Item are always rented for 30 days.

So the problem I am facing, is I need to somehow get which days an item can be rented and is available for at least 30 days from that point. (for example, a customer couldn't rent an item today if it is reserved to be rented 10 days from now)

In my database I have a rentals table that stores the pickup and delivery date.

I will be using a jQuery datepicker, and just need to load available dates 1 month at a time (I can redo the query each time the next month button is pressed to hide unavailable dates)

What would be the best approach to performing this type of query and getting all the days in a month in which an item is available for 30 days? I could always iterate through every single day in the month and check if there are any other records within 30 days, but that seems like a surplus of queries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the day an item is reserved to be picked up?  Make a query based on that.  Perhaps your Rental model has a `reserved_on` attribute?

```
class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :available, where('rented = ? AND reserved_on > ?', false, 30.days.from_now)

end
```

---

EDIT in response to comments

If are looking at a single object you could create methods on it something like this:

```
def last_available_day
  delivery_date && delivery_date - rental_period  # 30 days
end

def is_available_on?(date)
  return true unless last_available_day
  date <= last_available_day
end
```

Comment: I don't really, but for the sake of explaining the issue I assumed I have it. Both issues are very similarly solved with the same query.

How would you suggest doing it for an entire month? Getitng each day thats available? Would you just iterate through every day and do the query 30 times?
The query you showed should work great for checking a single day, thanks.

Comment: The query above should cover you for a full month, as it's checking to see if the reserved_on date is more than 30 days out.

Comment: Apologies, it's a bit difficult to fully explain. I'm hoping to get a list of days back where a customer could rent it and for each of those days it is available 30 days after. So I could query June for example, and it would give me back everyday in June where someone could rent the item and it's available for 30 days from each of those days. I hope that makes sense.